# How to know if 'contained database authentication' is turned on in SQL Azure?

Tags: sql-server-2012, azure-sql-database

Is there a query I can run to know if '*contained database authentication*' is turned on in a user-defined database in SQL Azure or SQL Server 2014?

I tried the following query but it does have a column for 'contained database authentication'?

```
select *  from   sys.databases 
where name='myDatbase';
```

Answer (score 5):

The following query will tell if contained database authentication is enabled. In query below, containment = 1 and containment_desc = 'PARTIAL' when this feature is enabled, else these values are 0 and 'NONE'.

So, just run this query in SSMS to know whether this feature is enabled. Replace the database name in query with whatever database you are using. In this case, I have used northwind database.

```
select containment, containment_desc  from   sys.databases 
where name='northwind'
```

**UPDATE 1**:

Below is a screen shot of what I found about this at [Containment & Containment_desc column values in sys.databases](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178534.aspx) under MSDN documentation.

[image]

Comment: I don't think you should rely on sys.databases for these features. containment is orthogonal to the contained users and it looks enabled in V12

Comment: We have a hosted SQL Azure database, and when I try to create a user in this database, it doesn't work. So how come you say its enabled by default in SQL Azure? I used 'CREATE USER [readonly] WITH PASSWORD = 'xyayaya@33332'', but it failed.

Comment: Your statement is not correct else I would have been able to create a user.

Comment: check if you are running on sql azure v12. Version: 12.0.2000.8

Comment: In v12 of SQL Azure, what will be the values for containment_desc  and containment columns in sys.databases ?

Comment: 0 and None but that didn't stop creating contained users. Look @ https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173463.aspx  and refer: Applies to: SQL Server (SQL Server 2008 through current version), Azure SQL Database, SQL Database V12, (Preview in some regions).

Comment: Look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178534.aspx, and then find 'containment' in that page. It clearly says that the values of 0 or 1 for containment applies to SQL Server 2014 and SQL Azure. Where in the url you gave in your last comment, does it mention that 'containment = 0 ' in SQL Azure even when contained database is enabled?

Comment: I tried it is working and documentation suggesting the same, contained database is more than supporting contained users, why don't you think that feature is forked out of contained databases. Please upgrade to v12 and give a shot.

Comment: It might be a default feature in v12, but then the values of those columns should not be 0 and 'NONE'. I will confirm this if I can get access to SQL Azure v12.

Answer (score 1):

It seems supported in Azure V12. I tried this and working fine:

create user user1 with password = 'MyPassw0rd' and then try login to login1. If possibe using contained users is a better option as it avoids round trip the master database which can potentially on a different sql instance

Answer (score 0):

Contained users are supported in Sql db  v12. Looks like you are on v11 and I don't think there is a catalog view to show the same. Contained databases comes with many other things beyond contained users , for example fixed catalog collation. In Azure logically all the databases are contained. So it made sense enabling contained users. The columns you are referring are for box compatible contained databases, and aren't in Azure.

Comment: My question is NOT about knowing whether its supported or not. In the SQL Azure version we are using, it is not supported by default. So, can you tell me how I can know whether its been enabled in the SQL Azure < 12.x  before running any create user queries?

Comment: I don't think there are any catalog views just related to this functionality and this particular feature is not supported in v11

Comment: So what does the screen shot that I posted refer to? Is that not for containment?

Comment: This feature is by default enabled for all the databases in SQL Azure and is not configurable. To answer your query check for (version > 12.0 and SERVERPROPERTY('EngineEdition') = 5) OR containment = 1. This rules out v11 databases from the equation and works for box and azure